# How to re render FlatList React Native when working with redux

Tags: react-native, redux, flatlist

I am new to React Native, I'm having trouble with FlatList. I assign extraData to a redux value but it does not re-render the FlatList when redux update. I think I should assign it to a local state, but I got too many re render error. Many thanks to anyone who help me!
Below is my code

```
function CartScreen() {
const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cartReducer);
console.log(cart);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(cartActions.refreshCartAction(cart));
}, []);

const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <CartItem book={item} />;
};

return (
    <View>
        <FlatList
            data={cart}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
            extraData={cart}
        />
    </View>
);
}

export default CartScreen;
```

Comment: Please give a wider picture with your redux & reducer implementation codes.

Comment: which error are you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an error in my redux action that solve the problem. Thank everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

If the data in the global state is asynchronous
You'll have to do that

```
{cart  && <FlatList
          data={cart}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item._id.toString()}
          extraData={cart}
       />
}
```